Question about Rudin's PMA 10.38
10.38  Theorem Suppose $E$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^n$, $f\in C^1(E)$, $p$ is an integer, $1\le p\le n$, and $$(D_jf)(x)=0\quad(p<j\le n,x\in E).\tag{116}\label{eq1A}$$
Then there exists an $F \in C^1(E)$ such that $$ (D_{p}F)(x)=f(x),\quad (D_{j}F)(x)=0\quad(p<j\leq n ,x \in E).$$*
Proof: Write $x=(x',x_{p},x'')$, where $$x'=(x_{1},\dots,x_{p-1}),\;x''=(x_{p+1},\dots ,x_{n}).$$ (When $p=1$, $x'$ is absent; when $p=n$, $x''$ is absent.) Let $V$ be the set of all $(x',x_p)\in\Bbb R^p$ such that $(x',x_p,x'')\in E$ for some $x''$. Being a projection of $E$, $V$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^p$. Since $E$ is convex and \eqref{eq1A} holds, $f(x)$ does not depend on $x''$. Hence there is a function $\varphi$, with domain $V$, such that $f(x)=\varphi(x',x_p)$, for all $x\in E$.
If $p=1$, $V$ is a segment in $\Bbb R^1$ (possibly unbounded). Pick $c \in V$ and define $$F(x)=\int_c^{x_1}\varphi(t)dt\quad(x\in E).$$
If $p>1$, let $U$ be the set of all $x'\in\Bbb R^{p-1}$ such that $(x',x_p)\in V$ for some $x_p$. Then $U$ is a convex open set in $\Bbb R^{p-1}$, and there is a function $\alpha\in C^1(U)$ such that $(x',\alpha (x')) \in V$ for every $x' \in U$. In other words, the graph of $\alpha$ lies in $V$ (Exercise 29). Define $$F(x)=\int_{\alpha(x')}^{x_p}\varphi(x',t)dt\quad(x\in E).$$

My question is in the case $p>1$. Why can we claim the continuously differentiable function $α$ exists, i.e. how can we solve the first part of Exercise 29 below?

29. Prove the existence of a function $α$ with the properties needed in the proof of Theorem 10.38, and prove that the resulting function $F$ is of class $C^1$. (Both assertions become trivial if $E$ is an open cell or an open ball, since $α$ can then be taken to be a constant. Refer to theorem 9.42.)
I guess we can use implicit function theorem to prove it, if we can regard $(x',x_p)\in V$ as an equation $\phi(x',x_p)=0, \phi\in C^1$. Is it possible?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

$V$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^p$. We cannot "regard $(x',x_p)\in V$ as an equation $\phi(x',x_p)=0, \phi\in C^1$". Did you try to use the hint in Exercise 29?
